# Replace blank space with new line in txt file with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, replace

If I have a .txt file with a whole bunch of data, lets say movie reviews that is currently formatted like this:

> 1 The Da Vinci Code book is just awesome.
>   1   this was the first clive cussler i've ever read, but even books like Relic, and Da Vinci code were more plausible than this.
>   1   i liked the Da Vinci Code a lot.
>   1   i liked the Da Vinci Code a lot.
>   1   I liked the Da Vinci Code but it ultimatly didn't seem to hold it's own.
>   1   that's not even an exaggeration ) and at midnight we went to Wal-Mart to buy the Da Vinci Code, which is amazing of course.

How could I alter this file or write its contents to a new file so that after the end of each sentence, the next starts on a new line rather than the same one?

Comment: Where are you getting this data from? It looks like you are getting it from scraping. In that case, you might have more luck trying to extract the formatting out of the original HTML data

Comment: @Azsgy it's from a sample dataset on Kaggle, I just saved the page to a file rather than scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the text at `"."` and then use string formatting:

```
import re
new_s = ['{}\n'.format(i) for i in re.split('\.\s*', open('filename.txt').read())]
with open('movie_listing.txt', 'a') as f:
  f.write(''.join(new_s))
```

Output (in `movie_listing.txt`):

```
1 The Da Vinci Code book is just awesome
1 this was the first clive cussler i've ever read, but even books like Relic, and Da Vinci code were more plausible than this
1 i liked the Da Vinci Code a lot
1 i liked the Da Vinci Code a lot
1 I liked the Da Vinci Code but it ultimatly didn't seem to hold it's own
1 that's not even an exaggeration ) and at midnight we went to Wal-Mart to buy the Da Vinci Code, which is amazing of course
```

Comment: `"\n".join(iterable)` is a much nicer (and more standard) way of doing that

Comment: @Ajax1234 I should have mentioned that the quoted part of my question is just a small section of the rest of the file. How would this be done by taking in the entire contents of the file?

Comment: @Kizzle You can open the original file, read the contents, and then pass to `re.split`. Please see my recent edit.